# Javascript .volume property doesn't work with float numbers

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, volume

I made some scripts to understand the javascript Audio, and have a problem about .volume.
Setting the value to 0 does the work, but any float numbers like 0.3 is not taken into consideration.

Here is a little player with play/pause and a looping randomized list. The comments are the 2 tests about volume.
The first one is applied on the first music played. The second one when a new music starts.
In the 2 cases, .volume = 0 works fine (it mutes the song) but any numbers like 0.2, 0.5 etc... doesn't put the sound down.

HTML

```
<div id="music" >MUSIC</div>
<style>
    #music {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 80px;
        margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 50px; 
        padding: 10px;
        background: blue;
    }
</style>
<script src="audio.js"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
class Music {
    constructor() {
        this.play();
    }
    playList = [new Audio('triangle.wav'), new Audio('drum.wav'), new Audio('guitar.mp3')];
    /* same randomized list at each repetition */
    shuffle(array) {
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            const temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
          }
          return array;
    }
    playListFinal = this.shuffle(this.playList);
    play() {
        let playStatus = 'off';
        let currentMusic = 1;
        document.getElementById('music').addEventListener("click", e => {
            switch(true) {
                case (playStatus == 'off') : {
                    playStatus = 'on';

                    /* 1st volume test, on 1st music played */

                    var test = this.playListFinal[currentMusic-1]
                    test.volume = 0.2;
                    test.play();
                    break;
                }
                case (playStatus == 'on') : {
                    playStatus = 'off';
                    this.playListFinal[currentMusic-1].pause();
                    break;
                }
            }
        })
        this.playListFinal.forEach( music => music.addEventListener("ended", event => {
            if (currentMusic == this.playListFinal.length) {
                currentMusic = 1;
            }
            else {
                currentMusic ++;
            }

            /* 2nd volume test, when a new music starts */

            this.playListFinal[currentMusic-1].volume = 0.2;
            this.playListFinal[currentMusic-1].play();
        }));
    }
}
const music = new Music;
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my problem, after further testing, it appears that the volume works fine on my phone, but not on PC.
I suspect my realtek audio driver to force the sounds to max volume, it's why I have an effect  only at really low values like 0.07, but in this case the sound become inconsistant (it diseapers after few clicks).